# .NET Sharepoint Create Directory

Tags: sharepoint, webclient, put

I can upload a file to sharepoint with the webclient as follows

```
using (System.Net.WebClient webclient = new System.Net.WebClient())
{
    System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
                    Encryptor.Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["username"]),
                    Encryptor.Decrypt(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]),
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["domain"]);
    webclient.Credentials = credentials;

    string path = Path.Combine("http://sharepoint.domain.com/dir", filename);
    webclient.UploadData(path, "PUT", fileBytes);
}
```

But I don't know how to create directories if they don't exist.

Any ideas how I can do that?

Thanks,
-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term "Directories" in a SharePoint site is deceptive.  The 'directory' structure of a SharePoint webservice is a virtual structure that is located in the SharePoint databases.  You need to identify what object in the SharePoint Object Model the 'directory' is for example: http://sharepoint.domain.com/dir is probably a SPSite, with in the site you can have a 'directories' that are SPFolders, SPLists, SPDocumentLibraries etc.

So if by "create directories that don't exist" you mean in the SharePoint site directory structure, you wont be able to do with the WebClient.  You have two options: the Windows SharePoint Services Object Model, and the SharePoint Webservices.

The object model is certainly easier to use in my opinion but it will require you to run the app on the same server as your SharePoint server.  The Webservices are a bit more work but it enables you to use them remotely.

You will need to identify what kind of object you are trying to add (e.g. SPFolder, SPSite, SPList, SPDocumentLibrary ect.).

There is ample documentation for using the object model located [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.aspx) but if you want to use the webservices you will need to access them at the following locations:

```
Administration Service       http://<server-url:port-number>/_vti_adm/admin.asmx
Alerts Service               http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/alerts.asmx
Document Workspace Service   http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/dws.asmx
Forms Service                 http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/forms.asmx
Imaging Service             http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/imaging.asmx
List Data Retrieval Service http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/dspsts.asmx
Lists Service                 http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/lists.asmx
Meetings Service               http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/meetings.asmx
Permissions Service         http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/permissions.asmx
Site Data Service             http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/sitedata.asmx
Site Service                   http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/sites.asmx
Users and Groups Service       http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/usergroup.asmx
Versions Service               http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/versions.asmx
Views Service                 http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/views.asmx
Web Part Pages Service       http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/webpartpages.asmx
Webs Service                   http://<server-url>/_vti_bin/webs.asmx
```

I suggest looking into the Lists or Document Workspace Service services.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That worked great, with two catches.
1. If you have subsites you need to include that in the URL so it tries creating the folder at the right place
2. You can only create one new directory at a time you can't create multiple levels at one time (ie. new/sub/folder)